# SQL Server: Automate Import Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am tring to update a table via a text file that is created by another system. I was thinking of automating the Import Wizard. Is this possible in SQL Server? I have accomplished this before in MS Access. I even had the import Specification saved and it ran 3 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the import wizard you're able to save the import as an SSIS package and then you can set up the import in the SQL Server Agent Jobs.

Comment: Or you can build an SSIS package if you need more flexibility than the wizard will give you.